# Text over background image issue

Tags: css, image

I am helping a student with a project and we are going through a tutorial.  The tutorial is here:
https://ihatetomatoes.net/demos/parallax-scroll-effect/

Here is our index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>joeys school project</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="js/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <section id="slide-1" class="homeSlide">
        <div class="bcg" data-center="background-position: 50% 0px;" data-top-bottom="background-position: 50% -100px;" data-anchor-target="#slide-1">
          <div class="hsContainer">
            <div class="hsContent" data-center="opacity: 1" data-106-top="opacity: 0" data-anchor-target="#slide-1 h2">
              <h2>Mac Vs. Windows</h2>
              <p>Which is better? Which should you choose?</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is our main.css:

```
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }
    .mac_header {
      z-index: 100;
      position: absolute;
      color: white;
      font-size: 24px;
      font-weight: bold;
      left: 150px;
      top: 350px;
    }
    /* CSS */
    .hsContainer {
        display: table;
        table-layout: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    .hsContent {
        max-width: 450px;
        margin: -150px auto 0 auto;
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        color: #ebebeb;
        padding: 0 8%;
        text-align: center;
    }
     .hsContent h2,
     .copy h2 {
       color: #ffffff;
       font-size: 45px;
       line-height: 48px;
       margin-bottom: 12px;
     }
     .hsContent p {
       width: 400px;
       margin: 0 auto;
       color: #b2b2b2;
     }
     .hsContent a {
       color: #b2b2b2;
       text-decoration: underline;
     }

    .bcg {
        background-position: center center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-size: cover;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    /* Slide 1 */
    #slide-1 .bcg {
     background-image:url('../img/computers-1227142.jpg');
     height: 733px;}
```

The issue is we can see the block for the text when we inspect the page in Chrome, but it is not displaying the text over the image.  All we see is the outline of the div where it is located.  We have researched how to get this working and also followed the tutorial correctly.  Also we have compared our code to the tutorial and can't see where the disconnect is.  Any ideas?  At this point a solution that works instead of what is in the tutorial will be fine as well.

Comment: Remove `opacity: 0` from `.hsContainer`

Comment: oh my, what a simple mistake.  Thanks, that was it.  I can't believe I didn't see that. :(